# How to run where clause on numeric string columns in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel app I use a table in which there is a string column to store long numbers. How can I run a whereBetwean on the relevant Model?

I try this and it doesn't work, the result is not what it supposed to be;

```
Model:whereBetween('number', [$startNumber, $endNumber])->get();
```

Comment: please specify what is $startnumber and $endnumber values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
Model::whereRaw('CAST(`number` AS SIGNED) BETWEEN ? AND ?', [(int)$startNumber, (int)$endNumber])
    ->get();
```

I have tried something similar on my end and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Model:whereBetween('number', [int($startNumber), int($endNumber)])->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

`whereBetween()` doesn't work, because you'd be comparing strings, not numbers. In order to compare strings like numbers, you need to convert them first.

```
Model::query()
  ->whereRaw('CONVERT(`number`, BIGINT) BETWEEN ? AND ?', [$startNumber, $endNumber])
  ->get();
```